# how do I get the revision name from buildbot

Tags: buildbot

In the `main.cfg` file I need to get the name of the current revision that is being built and create a folder with the name of that revision.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.buildbot.net/0.7.12/#Generalizing-VC-Systems

Most Source steps record the revision that they checked out in the got_revision property.

Answer (score 1):

From within a custom step start method you can retrieve `branch` and `revision` properties.
Something like:

```
from buildbot.steps.shell import ShellCommand

class MyStep(ShellCommand):
    def start(self):
        branch = self.getProperty('branch')
        revision = self.getProperty('revision')
        # Do watever, for example
        # self.setCommand('echo "Building %s"' % revision)
        ShellCommand.start(self)
```

You can read more about build properties in [the documentation](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-properties.html#properties)